# Convert HttpUrlConnection to OkHttpClient

Tags: http, okhttp, apollo-client

One of our Legacy code returns only `HttpUrlConnection` . I need to use ApolloClient to communicate to GraphQL server. Apollo Client uses `OkHttpClient` .

Is there anyway I can convert `HttpUrlConnection` to `OkHttpClient` ?

Alternatively ApolloClient suggests using [Http-Engine](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/http-engine/) to use any custom http client. Is there any way to use HttpUrlConnection for `HttpEngine` ?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? If you haven't, I think a question like this should be bountied. If yes, post your code and your guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by reading the header/request parameters from `HttpUrlConnection` and setting it in `ApolloClient`

```
ApolloClient.Builder builder = ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl(serverURI);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entries : httpURLConnection.getRequestProperties().entrySet()) {
            String values = "";
            for (String value : entries.getValue()) {
                values += value + ",";
            }
            builder.addHttpHeader(entries.getKey(), values);
            Log.d(TAG, entries.getKey() + " - " + values);
        }
        return builder.build();
```